# Функция printf(): как убрать нули?

Tags: java

```
out.printf("Srednee: %g\n", average);
```

Выводит мне функция, например, 1.500000. Как избавиться от лишних нулей? Конкретизировать количество знаков после запятой - предлагать не надо.

Comment: В вопросе видно некоторое недопонимание: не каждую десятичную дробь можно *точно* представить в виде двоичной. Посмотрите [пример, когда это не так](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/01/07/is-there-such-a-thing-as-too-much-precision.aspx): 108.595, к примеру, представляется как 108.594999999999998863131622783839702606201171875.

Comment: А по моему вопрос не про ограниченную разрядность, а про то как убрать лишние нули, не используя спецификатор точности форматного вывода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
avarage.replaceAll(0, "");
```

**UPD**

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();

format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);

Double d = 1.4000;
System.out.println( format.format(d) );
```

Comment: double average;

поэтому average.replaceAll(0, ""); не подходит

и можно, пожалуйста, поподробнее немного, новичок совсем.

Comment: ну все зависит от случая, например я бы так не делал, потому что эта функция заменит все нули в строке(что бы ей воспользоватся в твоес вариант, надо перевести дабл в стринг, убрать нули - вывести на экран), я обновил ответ, попробуй по другому, может подойдет...

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто

```
out.printf("Srednee: " + 1.2600);
```

Будет

```
Srednee: 1.26
```

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat ;
public class FormatDouble
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++ )
        {
            double value = (double) i / 3 ;

            System.out.println ( "'" + value + "' = '" + format ( value ) + "'" ) ;
        }

    }
    private static String format ( double value )
    {
        return NumberFormat.getInstance ().format ( value ) ;
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
'0.0' = '0'
'0.3333333333333333' = '0,333'
'0.6666666666666666' = '0,667'
'1.0' = '1'
'1.3333333333333333' = '1,333'
'1.6666666666666667' = '1,667'
'2.0' = '2'
'2.3333333333333335' = '2,333'
'2.6666666666666665' = '2,667'
'3.0' = '3'
'3.3333333333333335' = '3,333'
'3.6666666666666665' = '3,667'
'4.0' = '4'
'4.333333333333333' = '4,333'
'4.666666666666667' = '4,667'
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы от уважаемого ***jmu*** неплохое и весьма изящное. НО! Метод format из double возвращает String, разделителем в котором выступает запятая(в наших регионах) что делает невозможным обратное приведение из String в double. Нужно локализировать .getInstance ()

```
private static String format ( double value )
{
    return NumberFormat.getInstance (Locale.US).format ( value ) ;
}
```